# Slow plotting of trigonometric functions

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning

I have two sets of solutions for `a` and `b`. I'm plotting solution only if it is positive for both `a` and `b`.

```
 a = 2; b = 3;
 solutionsA[x_, a_, b_] = {a Sin[b*x], a Sin[b*x + Pi/2], a Sin[b*x + Pi]};
 solutionsB[x_, a_, b_] = {a Tan[b*x], a Tan[b*x + Pi/2], a Tan[b*x + Pi]};
 Plot[Select[
    Transpose[
      {solutionsA[x, a, b], solutionsB[x, a, b]}
    ]
   , (#[[1]] > 0 && #[[2]] > 0 ) &]
 , {x, 0, 10}, Exclusions -> {Cos[b*x] == 0, Sin[b*x] == 0}]
```

My output is very slow. Why?

Comment: @Öskå Is it possible to do the same without Select ?

Comment: @илипп Not that I know, but there must be different ways that others might know about.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get it about 5-6 times faster if you define a separate function (to do `Transpose` just once):

```
ClearAll[f]; 
f[x_?NumericQ] = 
   # * UnitStep[First @ #] * UnitStep[Last @ #] & /@ 
       Transpose[{solutionsA[x, a, b], solutionsB[x, a, b]}],
```

and the presence of `UnitStep` makes `Select` unnecessary, with visually the same output. You can then plot it as e.g.

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}, Exclusions -> {Cos[b*x] == 0, Sin[b*x] == 0}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 7}}]
```

A cleaner way to do this is to have a function generator that would embed your parameters, so that you don't have a dependence on global variables `a` and `b`:

```
makeF[a_, b_] := 
   Function[
      x, 
      # * UnitStep[First @ #] * UnitStep[Last @ #] & /@ 
         Transpose[{solutionsA[x, a, b], solutionsB[x, a, b]}]
   ]
```

and then

```
ClearAll[f];
f = makeF[a,b]
```

and then use `f` as before.

To get some further speed-up, you can compile this. Here is the corresponding function generator:

```
ClearAll[makeFC];
makeFC[a_, b_, opts___?OptionQ] :=
    Block[{x},Compile[x, Evaluate[makeF[a, b][x], opts]]]
```

Now you can do

```
fc = makeFC[a, b];
```

and then plot `fc`. I can't test now, but presumably by passing `CompilationTarget -> "C"` to `makeFC`, you can get the plotting faster still.

Answer (score 9):

A solution which outperforms the currently given answers is the following: You build up the complete expression of your function using `Which`, so that you have in the end

```
tuned[x_]:=Which[
  Positive[Sin[3 x]]&&Positive[Tan[3 x]],{2 Sin[3 x],2 Tan[3 x]},
  Positive[Cos[3 x]]&&Positive[-Cot[3 x]],{2 Cos[3 x],-2 Cot[3 x]},
  Positive[-Sin[3 x]]&&Positive[Tan[3 x]],{-2 Sin[3 x],2 Tan[3 x]},
  True,None]
```

This approach works even if you don't know specific values for `a` and `b`. To get the definition of `tuned` automatically from you two `solutionsA` and `solutionsB` the following injection code can be used:

```
With[{arg = Transpose[{solutionsA[x, a, b], solutionsB[x, a, b]}]},
 (tuned[x_] := #) & [
   Which @@ Sequence @@@ Append[{And @@ (Positive[#]), #} & /@ arg, {True, None}]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

On my machine, creating the graphics 10x gives the following timings for the different answers (I'm on my desktop pc now, so timings are in general faster):

- my approach 0.46 seconds. If I tweak it with `Compile` (see below) we can improve it to 0.21 seconds.
- the original approach of the OP takes 7.71 seconds.
- Leonid's compiled version 0.59 seconds and when you compile it to `"C"` then 0.55 seconds
- chyaongs needs 0.61 seconds

For testing, I iterated your original `Plot` command and measured the `AbsoluteTiming`. Let me point out that all current answers use the same approach and the tweaking to improve from 0.6 to 0.2 seconds isn't really worth it.

Let me give the code of my compiled version for comparison

```
With[{arg = Transpose[{solutionsA[x, a, b], solutionsB[x, a, b]}]}, 
 tunedC = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, #] &[
   Which @@ 
    Sequence @@@ 
     Append[{And @@ (Positive[#]), #} & /@ arg, {True, {0., 0.}}]]]
```

Comment: Did you test my compiled approach? Particularly, compiled to C?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I get for 10 runs (on my desktop PC now) for your compiled version 0.589 s, compiled to "C" 0.5604 and my version gives me 0.460.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin When I create a compiled version from my `Which` code, giving back `{0.0, 0.0}` instead of `None`, it runs in only 0.21 sec.

Comment: Thanks for the data. I already voted for your answer, in any case :)

Answer (score 7):

```
a = 2; b = 3;
solutions[f_, a_: a, b_: b] = a {f[b*x], f[b*x + Pi/2], f[b*x + Pi]};
expr = If[#1 > 0 && #2 > 0, {##}] & @@@ Transpose[solutions /@ {Sin, Tan}]
Plot[expr, {x, 0, 10}, Exclusions -> {Cos[b*x] == 0, Sin[b*x] == 0}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A nice compact one, using the two argument form of `UnitStep` and summing the solutions:

```
sol = Total @ MapThread[UnitStep[##] {##} &, {solutionsA[x, a, b], solutionsB[x, a, b]}]

Block[{a = 2, b = 3}, Plot[sol, {x, 0, 10}, Exclusions -> {Cos[b*x] == 0, Sin[b*x] == 0}]]
```

[image]